# Bucle infinito en programa que de la edad en año y meses

Tags: c

¿Por qué me arma un bucle infinito en el `for` para mostrar la edad? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Al ingresar la fecha actual 06/02/2020 y fecha de nacimiento 23/11/1999 me arma un bucle infinito con la edad de 21 años.

Es un programa para practicar en este lenguaje ya que me lo están enseñando en la universidad

Programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int dia_actual, mes_actual, ano_actual ;

    dia_actual = 0 ;
    mes_actual = 0 ;
    ano_actual = 0 ;

    int dia_nacimiento, mes_nacimiento, ano_nacimiento ;

    dia_nacimiento = 1 ;
    mes_nacimiento = 1 ;
    ano_nacimiento = 1 ;

    int calcula_edad, calcula_mes ;

    calcula_edad = 0 ;
    calcula_mes = 0 ;

    printf("\tFECHA ACTUAL\n\n") ;

    printf("Ingrese el dia: ") ;
    scanf("%i",&dia_actual) ;   
    printf("Ingrese el mes: ") ;
    scanf("%i",&mes_actual) ;
    printf("Ingrese el anio: ") ;
    scanf("%i",&ano_actual) ;

    printf("\n\nIngrese la fecha de su nacimiento\n\n") ;

    while(dia_nacimiento != 0 || mes_nacimiento != 0 || ano_nacimiento !=0){

        printf("Ingrese el dia: ") ;
        scanf("%i",&dia_nacimiento) ;   
        printf("Ingrese el mes: ") ;
        scanf("%i",&mes_nacimiento) ;
        printf("Ingrese el anio: ") ;
        scanf("%i",&ano_nacimiento) ;

        for(calcula_edad=0;ano_nacimiento<=ano_actual;calcula_edad++){

            calcula_edad = ano_actual - ano_nacimiento ;
            printf("\nLa edad es: %i\n\n",calcula_edad) ;

        }

    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Hola jose, es un ciclo infinito porque la condición `ano_nacimiento<=ano_actual ` jamás  resulta falsa ya que no modificas ninguna de las dos variables dentro del propio ciclo. De todas formas el for no tiene sentido, basta con una simple resta de ambas variables como haces dentro del ciclo, pero el ciclo en si sobra...

Comment: Exacto, si lo que deseas es calcular la edad esta demás el for, simplemente coloca lo que esta dentro.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por qué me arma un bucle infinito en el `for` para mostrar la edad?

Porque ese `for` es un bucle infinito. La condición de salida es una constante que tiene siempre el mismo valor. Para acabar el bucle, `ano_nacimiento` debe ser menor o igual a `ano_actual`:

```
for(calcula_edad=0;ano_nacimiento<=ano_actual;calcula_edad++){
//                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Condición de salida.
    calcula_edad = ano_actual - ano_nacimiento ;
    printf("\nLa edad es: %i\n\n",calcula_edad) ;

}
```

Pero ni `ano_nacimiento` ni `ano_actual` cambian de valor en el cuerpo del bucle `for`.